# webapp read text file ajax, httprequest, or

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, web-applications

I'm using jquery mobile to create a web app...
I would like to know what is the best way to read a text file?
At this moment, I have this functions working fine... But I don't know the differences between them, and which one is better to use? Or which is fastest...

Function 1

```
function readfileAjax() {
    $.get('txt/info.txt', function(txt) {
        var lines = txt.split(/\n/);
        var randLineNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);
        var text = lines[randLineNum];
        var parts = text.split(/#/);   
        var fullText = parts[0] + " " + parts[1] + " " + parts[2];
        $("#msg").append("<p>" + fullText + "</p>");
    });
}
```

Function 2

```
function readfileHttpRequest() {
    var filePath = "txt/info.txt";
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/plain');
    xmlhttp.open("GET",filePath,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
    var fileContent = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var lines = fileContent.split(/\n/);
    var randLineNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);
    var text = lines[randLineNum];
    var parts = text.split(/#/);   
    var fullText = parts[0] + " " + parts[1] + " " + parts[2];
    $("#msg").append("<p>" + fullText + "</p>");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Learn about what you are using. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 0):

Function1 uses jQuery which wraps the XMLHttpRequest. If you already have jquery it's probably easier to just use it the whole way.

There's no real appreciable difference between the two functions in terms of performance though.

EDIT:
All the more reason to use function1, there's no reason to make this synchronous. The 3rd argument on open set to false makes the request synchronous, which gives you no improvement and will block the interactivity of the page. A syncronous call means that it just blocks all execution until the request is completed. If you switch that to true, and use a callback then there's no appreciable difference.